# ElasticSearch service start command fails

Tags: java, elasticsearch, digital-ocean

I am trying to install ElasticSearch in digitalOcean.

I have successfully installed elasticsearch, but when I am trying to run this command to start server, I get "**[Fail]**" message in red color.

```
sudo service elasticsearch start
```

The webpage I am following : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-elasticsearch-on-ubuntu-14-04

What to do with it??
I dont find any log file to understand what is happening there

Comment: Could you provide some more info like the full error message?

Comment: Should be under /var/log/elasticsearch

Comment: which version of elasticsearch you are using?

Comment: Thanks guys.. but I have managed to work with it. It was my mistake.